# How to read complex definitions

Tags: c, pointers, definition

I wonder how to read a complex definition like that

```
int (*(*a())[]) ()) ;
```

And what is the order of reading such definitions ?

Comment: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*%28*a%28%29%29%5B%5D%29%28%29%3B) might be of interest.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, as it's a different signature, but it's close enough.  Basically this is a function, `a` that returns an array of function pointers that when called all return ints.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://cdecl.org/. It's a handy tool if you're new at reading these types of functions.